# Prevent deletion of apps from the Chrome App Launcher by other users

Tags: applications, google-chrome, permission

How do I protect apps inside the Chrome App Launcher on a MacBook from being deleted by different users of the laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Make their accounts non-admin.

You cannot stop an admin from doing anything.

System Prefs > Users & Groups

1. Unlock
2. Disable

[image]